# Do the gamma matrices and complete basis of real and complex 4 X 4 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, clifford-algebras

From this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101887/do-gamma-matrices-form-a-basis, I know that the gamma matrices can be used as the generators of an algebra with 16 basis elements as follows:

- 1 the identity matrix $\mathbb{1}$
- 4 matrices  $\gamma^\mu$
- 6 matrices  $\sigma^{\mu\nu}=\gamma^{[\mu}\gamma^{\nu]}$
- 4 matrices  $\sigma^{\mu\nu\rho}=\gamma^{[\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\rho]}$
- 1 matrix    $\sigma^{\mu\nu\rho\delta}=\gamma^{[\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^{\delta]}=i\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\delta}\gamma^5$

In the answers, it is claimed that linear combination with complex coefficients of these 16 elements forms a complete basis of $M(4,\mathbb{C})$.

---

My question is: Is a linear combination with **real** coefficient forms a complete basis of $M(4,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Can you provide a definition of the $\gamma$ matrices you are using? I am used to a definition in which some of the entries are imaginary, and so aren't even in the space of real $4\times 4$ matrices!

Comment: @or1426 Just the usual definition as shown here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices. Are you then saying the answer is negative?

Comment: Look at $\gamma^2$, as given on the wiki page. What does this thing have to to with $M(4,\mathbb{R})$?